# Converting find and copy in bash to some in Windows PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, find

I am trying to convert code from bash to PowerShell like this:

In bash:

```
find ./searchfolder -type f -name "something" | xargs cp -t ./destinationfolder
```

I mean "find" command finds

```
./searchfolder/something

./searchfolder/0.15/something

./searchfolder/0.25/something
```

and "copy" command copies the files in the new directory (with preserving folder structure)

```
./destinationfolder/something

./destinationfolder/0.15/something

./destinationfolder/0.25/something
```

How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get-ChildItem to find files... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1 and Copy-Item Cmdlet to copy...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: I couldn't collect together. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the Filter parameter on the Copy-Item command? This might get you close.

```
cp ".\searchfolder" -Recurse -Filter "something" -Destination ".\destinationfolder"
```

`cp` is an Alias of `Copy-Item` BTW.

Comment: That fails. In a loop, code creates searchfolder contents. Like, ./destinationfolder/searchfolder/destinationfolder/searchfolder

Comment: I tested again your answer. Actually, your answer works. Previous problem was caused by putting the destinationfolder inside the searchfolder. That was my stupid fault.Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are looking for text files in C:\temp and moving them to C:

```
 Get-Childitem –Path C:\Temp -Recurse  -Include *.txt* | ForEach-Object {  mv $_.fullName  c:\ }
```

Regards!

Comment: This is not preserving the folder structure, only move to a folder.

Comment: Aliases are frowned upon in scripts.

Comment: you mean? solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this will be the folder structure. Only one Subdirectory inside Sourcefolder.

```
SourceFolder
  --f1
    -test.txt
  --f2
    -test.txt
  --f3
    -other.txt
```

and copy folders which has file named test

```
Destination
  --f1
    -test.txt
  --f2
    -test.txt
```

Script

```
cd D:\Vincent\PSTesting

$Path = 'Searchfolder'

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Filter *Test*  -File | foreach {
    $SourceFolder = $_.Directory -replace "^.*$Path"
    Copy-Item -Path $Path\$SourceFolder -Destination "D:\Vincent\PSTesting\Destinationfolder\" -Verbose -Recurse

}
```

Comment: My folder structure is just as you say. However, I could not run the script correctly. I tried different $Path like D:\Vincent\PSTesting, PSTesting but depending on the changes, either the script does nothing or searches on $SourceFolder in the nested directory like D:\Vincent\PSTesting\D:\Vincent\PSTesting. I think $Path should be removed from Copy-Item. What should I write in the $Path and also where am I making mistakes? Thanks a lot.